# How do you detect if a list has exactly 3 items in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, syntax

I have this but I got an error:

```
-- test if a list contains exactly three characters
test :: [Char] -> Bool
test xs   | [_ , _ , _] = True
          | otherwise = False
```

Comment: I have to say, I much prefer `[_, _, _]` to `[_ , _ , _]`.

Comment: What error have you got?

Comment: The answers here are more than what I asked for. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pattern matching happens on the *left* side of the vertical bar. Thus:

```
test :: [Char] -> Bool
test [_, _, _] = True
test _         = False
```

As [Norman Ramsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41661/norman-ramsey) rightly notes below, the following code is **not** a robust alternative solution (because it is very inefficient when applied to (long) finite lists and does not halt on infinite lists) and should thus **not** be used:

```
test :: [Char] -> Bool
test xs = length xs == 3
```

Moreover, `length xs == 0` should always be replaced with `null xs`.

**Edit:** the question which naturally arises is: *how do we generalize this?* What if we want to test whether a list has exactly *n* elements? What if the input may be infinite? 
Here's a solution where the cost is either `n` or the length of the list, whichever is smaller—and that's as efficient a solution, asymptotically, as we can possibly hope for:

```
hasLength :: Int -> [a] -> Bool
hasLength n []     = n == 0
hasLength 0 (x:xs) = False
hasLength n (x:xs) = hasLength (n-1) xs
```

Usage:

```
*Main> hasLength 3 [1..2]
False
*Main> hasLength 3 [1..3]
True
*Main> hasLength 3 [1..4]
False
*Main> hasLength 3 [1..] 
False
```

It is **unsafe** to call this function with a negative length; if the list is infinite, the function won't terminate, and if the list is finite, it will return `False` with cost proportional to the length of the list.  An easy fix would be to check in advance (on the first call only) that `n` is nonnegative, but this fix would ugly up the code.

Comment: Ugh!  I was with you right up to the `length` example.  It's too close to a classic beginner mistake: writing `length xs == 0` instead of `null xs`.

Comment: Or if you want to get fancy, I think the point-free form would be `test = (3 ==) . length`

Comment: @MatrixFrog: Please, no!!!   @Stephan: `null` won't help with this problem.   My point, which I failed to make clearly, is that many beginners use `length` when they should use either `null` or pattern matching.  Encouraging `length` as a solution to this problem is to encourage programming with reckless disregard for costs, and programming that will fail on infinite lists.  Your `hasLength` function, on the other hand, is more on the right track.  I'm going to edit; if you don't like the edits, roll them back.  If you do like them, drop `length` from your answer so I can upvote it :-)

Comment: @Norman: thanks for the clarification! Feel free to edit and drop the reference to `length`. While you're at it, add `import Data.List` :)

Comment: I choose to add a clear warning above the code which uses `length`, instead of removing it completely; that's more educational. The alternative implementation of `hasLength` doesn't require `import Data.List`.

Comment: Sweet.  Nice collaborating with you.  It is tempting to add `haslength n l = n >= 0 && test n l where test n [] = n == 0...`  to fix the "negative length" problem.

Comment: `hasLength n = not . null . drop (n-1)`

Comment: @Porges: that fails for lists with length `> n`.

Comment: @Stephan202: No it doesn't. `let hasLength n = not . null . drop (n-1) in hasLength 3 [1..] == True`

Comment: @Porges: `[1..]` has infinite length, is does *not* have exactly three items. So `hasLength 3 [1..]` should return `False`.

Comment: Here is a correct version: `hasLength n xs = case drop (n-1) xs of { (_:[]) -> True; _ -> False }`

Comment: @Porges: that code looks very similar to my initial attempt (which used `splitAt`)! Note that `n == 0` should be handled as a special case. Using `drop` has the advantage that the code will not loop on negative inputs, but `haslength n [x]` will yield `True` if `n` is negative.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write something like

```
hasLength3 :: [a] -> Bool
hasLength3 xs = xs `hasLength` 3

hasLength :: [a] -> Int -> Bool
hasLength = foldr go stop
  where
    go _ r n = n > 0 && r (n - 1)
    stop n = n == 0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
main = do
  a:b:c:[] <- pure "123"  -- fails in runtime in MonadFail if they are not exactly 3
  print a >> print b >> print c
```